# Convert output file with the following columns to CSV removing the pipes

Tags: uninstall, output, pipe, csv

This is what I have in my output file:

```
    v6_ntoa    |   v6_ntoa    |     id      | client_syn_packets
---------------+--------------+-------------+--------------------
 105.245.90.61 | 82.17.112.84 | 15426766476 |                  1
```

I would like this to be converted to csv file in the following format:

105.245.90.61,82.17.112.84,15426766476,1

Need your help please (sed, awk or any other way). I tried several different ways but unable to remove pipes and proper spacing.

Comment: Is there only a single line of data? Do you want to preserve the header information?

Comment: don't have to keep the header info. yes, it's a single line of data

Comment: have you tried my solution? https://askubuntu.com/a/1395720/796708

Answer (score 1):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/) and tail, and running

```
<input.txt tail -n +3 | mlr --csv --ifs "|" -N clean-whitespace
```

you have

```
105.245.90.61,82.17.112.84,15426766476,1
```

Some notes:

- `<input.txt tail -n +3` to output only the record you want
- `--ifs "|"`, to set the field separator
- `-N` to set no heading input and output
- `clean-whitespace` to clean the whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest:

```
$ sed -n '3s/ *| */,/gp' file
 195.245.90.61,62.17.112.84,15426766476,1
```

(note however that this does leave a leading space; you could add another substitute to remove that if it's a problem).

If you want to get fancy, use GNU awk and define a field as any sequence of non-space-or-bar characters:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[^ |]+"; OFS=","} NR==3{$1=$1; print}' file
195.245.90.61,62.17.112.84,15426766476,1
```

or to preserve headers

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[^ |]+"; OFS=","} NR%2{$1=$1; print}' file
v6_ntoa,v6_ntoa,id,client_syn_packets
195.245.90.61,62.17.112.84,15426766476,1
```